# Powerpoint forces random date in footer when including date and time

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

I'm using PowerPoint 2003 on Windows XP. When I choose Insert > Date and Time and choose to add the date to the footer, it adds today's date in whatever format I specify, but it also adds the date April 28, 2009 immediately following the correct date. The April date does not change format and does not appear to be the creation, modification or access date for the file. If I uncheck date and time on the footer, both dates disappear.

I'd really like to use PowerPower's footer rather than add a textbox to each slide and update it every day, but it's useless at the moment. Anyone have any ideas about how to remove the extra date?

Comment: Just tried this on the same setup (PowerPoint 2003/ XP) and couldn't reproduce it. Is this possibly happening because of a company template? Are you sure the "fixed" date field doesn't have a predefined field that when you activate the "Update Automatically" it doesn't get activated as well.

Comment: Per Matt's line - check your Master slide. View > Master > Slide Master

Comment: Thank you both, that did it. Variant you were right on. If you want to turn those comments into answers, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David - as Matt was pointing to above, check your master slide for the textbox containing your extra date:

1. Click View in your menu bar
2. Select Master
3. Click Slide Master